# Serialize a complex class to a simple string

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have a "complex" (rather simple, but still containing members I do not want serialized) class that defines an implicit conversion from/to string. (It can reconstruct all it's data from that one string).

This class is used for members of a more complex class de/serialized by JSON.

With no other configuration, JSON is able to use this conversion to construct this type, when it is sent from browser.
What I would need is some simple way to tell JSON to ignore ALL the members of the class and just serialize the class as if it was a string.

I studied existing answers, but they all demand quite heavy work with creating custom serializers. I hope for a solution where all necessary configuration would be done using attributes on the one class.
I it a part of quite a big project and changing configuration and behavior of the whole app is not practicable.

What it produces now is:

```
"SomeOtherMemberOfClass: "Some value",
"MemberOfMyType": {
    "UnimportantMember1": true,
    "UnimportantMember2": 123456789,
    "TheImportantString": "I want to see this"
  }
```

I would like it to produce:

```
"SomeOtherMemberOfClass: "Some value",
"MemberOfMyType": "I want to see this"
```

As I said, if the browser sends the data in my desired format, my class deserializes just fine, but it still sends the member as a complex type, which is undesirable.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class looks like this:

```
public class MemberOfMyType
{
    public bool UnimportantMember1 { get; set; }
    public int UnimportantMember2 { get; set; }
    public string TheImportantString { get; set; }
}
public class GoodClass
{
    public MemberOfMyType MemberOfMyType { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherMemberOfClass { get; set; }
}
```

You can then use the [JsonConverterAtrribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonConverterAttributeClass.htm) to achieve what you want. 
Decorate your class with the `JsonConverterAtrribute`like below.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(GoodCassConverter))]
public class GoodClass
{
    public MemberOfMyType MemberOfMyType { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherMemberOfClass { get; set; }
}

public class GoodClassConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        MyGoodClass myclass = value as MyGoodClass;

        writer.WriteValue(myclass..); //do your thing here.
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        MyGoodClass myclass = new MyGoodClass();
        myclass.SomeOtherMemberOfClass = (string)reader.Value; //do some stuffs with the string here.

        return myclass;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(MyGoodClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that should work. (I also upvoted you, but as I'm new here, it doesn't mean much).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Json.NET, I think a [custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) is about as lightweight as you're going to get. Your requirement is not simply to *ignore certain members*, it's to serialize a complex object as if it were a string, and deserialize a string to a complex object.

Comment: Thanks. This could work as long as there is a way to tell JSON to use my converter without changing config of the project.